postgresql nextval() can't find sequence number
I am getting an error when trying to insert a postgres record using nextval.  It just started not working when I changed from using a custom databasename to 'postgres'
2024-08-20 10:07:39 2024-08-20 14:07:39.198 UTC [118] ERROR:  column "PATIENT_VISIT_SEQ" does not exist at character 601

2024-08-20 10:07:39 2024-08-20 14:07:39.198 UTC [118] STATEMENT:  insert into myschema.patient_visit (PATIENT_VISIT_SEQ, CARE_ID, OUT_PRIMARY_EXCHANGE_ALT_ID, OUT_SECONDARY_EXCHANGE_ALT_ID, IN_PRIMARY_EXCHANGE_DROP_ID, FACILITY_ID, MEDICAL_RECORD_NUM, PATIENT_LAST_NM, PATIENT_MIDDLE_NM, PATIENT_FIRST_NM, PATIENT_ID, PATIENT_ACCT_NUM, PATIENT_CLASS_CD, SUBSCRIBER_LAST_NM, SUBSCRIBER_MIDDLE_NM, SUBSCRIBER_FIRST_NM, SUBSCRIBER_ID, ADMISSION_DT, DISCHARGE_DT, CREATE_DT, LOAD_DT, GENDER, DOB, PRODUCT)  values (nextval('myschema.PATIENT_VISIT_SEQ'), $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18, $19, $20, $21, $22, $23)

(this is from the postgres log itself)

I have confirmed that the sequence myschema.patient_visit_seq does exist, and that the user role I am using has access.
In a console logged in using the same credentials, I can successfully execute
select nextval('myschema.PATIENT_VISIT_SEQ');

I can also successfully execute
insert into myschema.patient_visit (PATIENT_VISIT_SEQ) values (nextval('myschema.PATIENT_VISIT_SEQ'));

I am running postgres in a docker container: "postgres:13"
I am at a loss as to why the app code stopped working.
Suggestion on how to proceed?

The error is displayed above
I expect the insert statement to grab the nextval from the sequence.


create table if not exists myschema.patient_visit
(
    patient_visit_seq             bigint not null,
    out_primary_exchange_alt_id   varchar(50),
    in_primary_exchange_drop_id   varchar(50),
    facility_id                   varchar(20),
    medical_record_num            varchar(100),
    patient_last_nm               varchar(60),
    patient_middle_nm             varchar(25),
    patient_first_nm              varchar(35),
    patient_id                    varchar(80),
    patient_acct_num              varchar(50),
    patient_class_cd              varchar(1),
    subscriber_last_nm            varchar(60),
    subscriber_middle_nm          varchar(25),
    subscriber_first_nm           varchar(35),
    subscriber_id                 varchar(80),
    admission_dt                  timestamp,
    discharge_dt                  timestamp,
    create_dt                     timestamp default now(),
    load_dt                       timestamp default now(),
    gender                        varchar(2),
    dob                           timestamp,
    out_secondary_exchange_alt_id varchar(100),
    product                       varchar(128),
    care_id                       decimal(38, 10),
    delete_dt                     timestamp,
    primary key (patient_visit_seq)
);

create index if not exists ie1_patient_visit on myschema.patient_visit (in_primary_exchange_drop_id, facility_id,
                                                               medical_record_num, patient_acct_num);

create index if not exists patient_visit_i1 on myschema.patient_visit (in_primary_exchange_drop_id, facility_id, admission_dt);

create index if not exists patient_visit_i3 on myschema.patient_visit (in_primary_exchange_drop_id, facility_id, load_dt);

create index if not exists patient_visit__care_id on myschema.patient_visit (care_id, patient_visit_seq);

create index if not exists patient_visit__load_dt on myschema.patient_visit (load_dt);

create index if not exists patient_visit__out_sec_load_dt on myschema.patient_visit (out_secondary_exchange_alt_id, load_dt);

create index if not exists patient_vis__out_sec_admit_dt on myschema.patient_visit (out_secondary_exchange_alt_id, admission_dt);

CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS myschema.patient_visit_seq as bigint;

the user:
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE postgres TO clinical_encounter;
GRANT ALL ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA myschema TO clinical_encounter;


We originally had a database 'clinical_encounter' and put all the schemas in that database.  For reasons out of my control we put all our schemas in the 'postgres' database and give the clinical_encounter user full rights.


Could you please share the error?

Why are you using UPPER case for object names? This is your current problem or it will become a problem in the near future. Only use lower case for object names like tables, columns, sequences, etc.

Not enough information. Add as text update to question text: 1) The error you are getting. 2) What you expect to happen, what is actually happening. 3) The table definition for myschema.patient_visit 4) An explanation of what this ... I changed from using a custom databasename to 'postgres' means? FYI, you should not be using the postgres database for user data.

UPPER case - legacy code, not an issue yet.

use of postgres database - I agree but its out of my control

the error was in the original post, but hidden, You can see it now:
ERROR:  column "PATIENT_VISIT_SEQ" does not exist at character 601

"it just started not working when I changed from using a custom databasename to 'postgres'" This makes no sense. "postgres" is the name of the default database created for every new cluster. You typically cannot use "postgres" as name for your database.

Why don't you add that sequence as default value of your table's PK alter table myschema.patient_visit alter column patient_visit_seq set default nextval('myschema.patient_visit_seq'::regclass); and avoid invoking it manually in every insert. By the way your table PK and the sequence both have the same name which is also a bad idea.

The error is at character 601, but the statement you gave us is only 589 characters long
